# Android studio spamming multiple openjdk binary plaform process

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

whenever I run an application of build gradle, android studio opens multiple instances of openjdk binary plaform.

1. I have turned off hotspot. And went further to turning on airplane mode
2. I have started android studio as administrator
3. I have done this:
   use `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` in the gradle.properties instead of `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

This is really annoying.

I use:
Android studio 4.1.2

[image: image showing multiple java.exe instances]

Gradle build:
**
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:
\Users\Heavenly\AndroidStudioProjects\PhotoGalleryX

Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 4 s 63 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 3 s 688 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 3 s 550 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 3 s 639 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 3 s 766 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 3 s 945 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 3 s 986 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 3 s 840 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 3 s 890 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 4 s 58 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 3 s 966 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 4 s 126 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 4 s 379 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 4 s 511 ms
Starting Gradle Daemon...
**

Comment: Why is that annoying? Gradle (the gradle daemon) runs on a JVM so it is required. javac cobtains java code and needs another JVM. It is the same thing for other (android) tools that are required.

Comment: it starts multiple instances rather than 2 to 4. I just attached an image representation

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you cannot do anything about it. It's just how it's made and how it works. As mentioned by @dan1st, Gradle daemon runs on first JVM, compilation needs another and so the android tools. However, it's a different case scenario if more than 4-5 JVMs are running. If that is the issue, try switching off the mobile hotspot in windows, because the gradle server doesn't accept connection from a daemon while hotspot is running. Add `-Xmx3G` to your gradle.properties also. Post the error log from `%UserProfile%\.gradle\daemon\daemon-version for android-studio\`.

Comment: It keeps opening new instances... more than 20... until my PC run out of memory

Comment: Post your gradle log please.

Comment: I've attached an image representation of what happens.

Comment: Copy the contents of your build tab and paste it here using pastebin please.

Comment: I've done exactly that

Comment: @Kennedy Fixed the answer. It should stop spamming now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting this properry

```
org.gradle.workers.max=(max # of worker processes)
```

as described at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties